# Vimeo video white screen issue on page load in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, vimeo

I am using below iframe to load the vimeo video.

```html
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="100%" height="349" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="example-video"
    name="example-video" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
```

White screen is shown on Internet explorer on page load, but the play/pause buttons are shown.
Video thumbnail is not shown on IE11 for the below versions:

> 11.0.9600.18954,
>   11.1155.15063.0,
>   11.2189.14393.0 and higher versions.

[image]

I found the issue is with the background image which is not being rendered only in IE versions (11.0.9600.18954 and 11.0.9600.19036 ) and the class 'vp-preview-cover' is not being added to the element with data attribute 'data-thumb'.
I am facing an security issue when i'm trying to open the background image in a new tab. Attached the screenshot of the same.
[image]

Comment: need full document source in order to replicate; please make a gist and share.

Comment: The Width is 100%. What is its container's width?

Comment: @albert I don't have any specific document source. I have mentioned all the info I have about this issue.

Comment: @nixkuroi in my application iframe's container's width is 439px.

Comment: @Divya what document is the iframe being embedded in? that is the source we seek.

Comment: Added more info to the above query, found that issue is with the background image.

Answer (score 1):

We have tested this across multiple versions of IE (with the highest being 11.492.16299.0) with your attached  and were not able to reproduce. Without more information or a page as an example it is difficult for us to help you.

Comment: I found the issue is with the background image which is not being rendered only in IE versions (11.0.9600.18954 and 11.0.9600.19036 ) and the class 'vp-preview-cover' is not being added to the element with data attribute 'data-thumb'.

Comment: Rebecca Sich 
Can you please suggest a solution for this issue.
Similar issue in more detail:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708557/vimeo-video-background-image-thumbnail-is-not-being-loaded-on-ie-11-2